# How to write an output of multiple simultaneous R script into a single file?

Tags: r, bash, output

For my simulations, I wrote a little loop to run multiple (n=20) instances of "my_script.R" simultaneously:

```
#! /bin/bash 
declare -i i=1 n=20

while [ $i -le $n ]; do
echo "#!/bin/bash --login" >my.qsub.${i} 
echo "#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1" >> mu.qsub.${i} 
echo "#PBS -l mem=2GB" >> my.qsub.${i} 
echo "cd /~path to my wd/"   >> my.qsub.${i} 
echo "module load  R/3.0.1" >> my.qsub.${i} 
echo -n 'R CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave --no-timing my_script.R ' >> my.qsub.${i} 
echo "" >> my.qsub.${i} 
qsub -l walltime=03:59:00 my.qsub.${i} 
sleep 2
let i+=1
done
```

Within "my_script.R", I have a for loop (n=1,...,B), which writes it's results into a "fnam" .txt file in the end of each iteration:

```
cat(file=fnam, append=TRUE, Results[n,], "\n")
```

Everything works fine, BUT it looks like there may be a problem if two different instances of the same R scrip try to append the fnam file simultaneously.

Did anyone try to synchronize/order the way, in which multiple instances of the same R script append the same output file?

Comment: I'd probably write to a separate file each time and do the collation into one file afterwards.

Comment: Good suggestion! I will go ahead and follow it:-)

Answer (score 1):

They jobs will need to write to different files which you will have to combine after. You can submit all the jobs at once as as 'Array Job' using `qsub -t 20 -sync y`. That will create 20 identical jobs and wait for all of them to finish before returning. Each job can get a unique identifier for itself via the environment variable `SGE_TASK_ID` from which it can craft a unique filename. The `sync` option will make qsub wait until they complete before returning and then you can concatenate all the files together.

Comment: Great suggestion! As cory suggested as well, different instances of my job should write their outputs into different files, that can be combined later on.